# Changing Default Boot Target in OSX

Tags: linux, macos, uefi, grub2, refit

I have a MacBook with both a Linux installation as well as OSX on it. I have GRUB2 configured to boot both successfully, but when I boot into OSX it seems to automatically alter the EFI boot configuration and make OSX the default boot target.

It's possible, with 'bless', to change the next boot target, but this seems to be reset yet again if I:

1. 'bless' the GRUB2 boot loader.
2. Boot into Linux.
3. Boot into OSX.
4. Reboot.

At this point, I want GRUB2 to be loaded again, but instead OSX seems to boot directly.

What's the trick to making this behave the way I want (that is, again, to have GRUB2 boot every time I power on this laptop, regardless of what OS I boot into thereafter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't happen to have ever installed rEFIt on this computer, would you? If so, you may just need to remove the rEFItBlesser application, which normally resides at `/Library/StartupItems/rEFItBlesser`. rEFIt installs this program to keep itself configured as the default boot manager, but if you've uninstalled rEFIt but didn't uninstall rEFItBlesser, it might just keep trying to re-install rEFIt and fail, but in the process de-register GRUB as the default boot manager. This is somewhat speculative, but it's certainly worth checking.

Comment: That did it! I have no idea why it never occurred to me that rEFIt was the culprit, rather than OS X itself. Thanks!